# Process safe logging library for c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, logging, log4cxx

Is there any process safe logging library which can write same file
from multiple process for C++?

I tried log4cxx. Some advices to use SocketConnector to write same file. But i did not find any real working sample.But any way i do not want my logger api open a tcp connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at logging using ETW points? It facilitates logging text strings as well. Downside is that your logs won't be human readable unless run through some other tools.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx